# How do I add typings for my JavaScript module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

This is definitely a duplicate but I am having a hard time figuring out how to add types like d.ts to my library/module.

I tried editing my `package.json` and adding `"types": "./typings/index.d.ts"` and it doesn't seem to work, so maybe I'm just doing it wrong.

It is also using an old library where I'm using it as an API, and this module is just a client wrapper for it.

References :

```js
// index.d.ts

export class Message {
    constructor(client: any, message: any)
    attachments: any[];
    body: string;
    isGroup: boolean;
    mentions: { [id: string]: string };
    messageID: string;
    senderID: string;
    threadID: string;
    isUnread: boolean;
    type: 'message';
}
```

```js
// Message.js

class Message {
    constructor(_client, event) {
        for (const key in event) {
            if (event.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this[key] = event[key];
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Message;
```

```js
// MessageCreate.js (Event handler)

const Message = require('../../structures/Message');

module.exports = (client, event) => {
    const message = new Message(client, event);
    client.emit('messageCreate', message);
}
```

```js
// index.js (main script)

const MessengerClient = require("./src/client/Client");

const appState = require('./appState.json');
const client = new MessengerClient();

client.on('ready', (client) => {
    console.log(`Logged in as '${client.user.name}'`);
})

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => { // Here, I want to add a type for message
    console.log(message);
})

client.login(appState);
```

```js
// Client.js

const login = require("../lib/index");
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');
const Events = require('./Event.js');

class MessengerClient extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        super();
        this.api = null;
        this.options = options;
        this.user = null;
    }
    
    async login(appState) {
        try {
            const api = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                login(appState, (err, api) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve(api);
                    }
                });
            });
            
            this.api = api;
            const clientID = api.getCurrentUserID();
            const clientUser = await api.getUserInfo(clientID);
            this.user = clientUser[clientID];
            new Events(this);
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during login:', error);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = MessengerClient;
```

Comment: You need to add an overload signature for MessengerClient.prototype.on but you haven't typed that class...or shown it to us in the code you posted.

Comment: @JaredSmith I edited my question, could you check again?

Comment: Much better, posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a declaration for your MessageClient class and add an [overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) for the `on` method. I usually just write Typescript rather than writing declaration files by hand but it should look something like this:

```
export class MessageClient {
    api: null | whatever; // replace with real type
    options: null | whatever; // replace with real type
    user: null | whatever; // replace with real type

    login(state: whatever): Promise<void>; // replace with real type
    
    on(evtType: 'messageCreate', cb: (msg: Message) => void): void
    on(evtType: string, cb: (result?: any) => void): void // you may want unknown here instead of any
}
```

Note that overloads should generally be more-specific to less-specific from top to bottom.

I feel compelled to say this: I realize that you may not be responsible and you may not be able to change it but that code is **poorly designed**. Having a class that has a bunch of null properties at construction that get initialized at some point in the future is an [OO antipattern](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/partially-initialized-entities-anti-pattern/).

If this class needs the login info in order to be properly instantiated then `login` ***should not be a method of that class***. Pull it out into a function and instantiate MessengerClient only once you have it then *get rid of all the* `| null`s.

Using constructors for side-effects (like the `new Events(this);` that doesn't get assigned to anything) is *also* another [OO antipattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/343447/should-constructors-ever-be-used-only-for-side-effects). Don't see enough code to advise you differently there but this is a common enough problem that Javascript linters have [rules against doing that](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-new) (you are using a linter in this project...right?).

Comment: Did this and it's still not working (whenever I hover to the message it's still `any`)

Comment: @Ruri 1. it will only work (and can *only ever* work) if the event type is a compile-time constant like a string literal. 2. How are you checking? That *should* work, so I would test the test by changing (result?: any) to something like (result: number) and see if the tooltip in your IDE changes.